# Device connected to internet but IE gives DNS error?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-ce

I have a device that is using Windows CE. I am connected to a LAN and pinging tells me that the device is connected to the internet. However when I try to open google in IE, it won't open the page and gives me a DNS error. Also, if I try to ping google i get "error 11010". Does anyone know what could be causing this?

**Edit: On closer inspection, it appears that this behavior (DNS error) only happens with https, when using http i get a blank gray page with text "IIS7", so not much better.**

**Edit 2: I have tried the workaround here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957639 and I am still getting the same error. Is this a CE 5.0 error?**

Comment: Is the device configured to use a static IP address? If so, is there a DNS server configured?

Comment: @DavidLaPorte The device does not have a static IP. DHCP is enabled and there is a DNS server configured

Answer (score 0):

You get that IIS7 page accessing any internet website?
It seems that the device has been redirected in some ways.
You are able to ping internet web sites, but HTTP (and maybe also HTTPS) traffic in your lan may be redirected using a proxy server or something like that. Maybe checking with your network admin can be a good idea.

Comment: Actually I can't ping internet websites. I get an error "Transmit failed, error code 11010" when I do that from the device.

Comment: Also the "IIS7" text appears to be shown as an error, rather than as a redirect. The page still says the correct URL that I was aiming at, but it's not loaded properly.

Comment: Can you ping devices in your LAN? Is the issue limited to internet websites or the device does not connect to any other device in LAN?

Comment: I can ping other devices on the LAN, and I can also ping the CE device from my computer. The problem is only with websites. Other devices on the LAN have no problems with internet connectivity.

Comment: Other devices are PCs or also embedded devices. Can you open a web page on a server inside the LAN? Looks like some kind of HTTP redirect to me. Did you try from other LANs (maybe just connecting the device to a home-router or something like that)? Do you have other network adapters on your device?